# internet explorer 11 zonemap not working when using HKLM

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users), for all versions prior to Internet Explorer 11, it should be possible to use the HKLM hive to set Intranet/Trusted Sites zone assigments, noting:

- they will not be visible from within the UI
- HKCU + HKLM settings are additive so you have to take care to make sure the 
  same site isn't in two zone mappings.

My testing on Internet Explorer 11 - Windows 10 (1610 + Creators Update), suggests that the HKLM hive is ignored, and these settings **only** work under HKCU.

Here's an example that *doesn't* work, this should set google.com as a Trusted Site:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\domains\google.com]
"https"=dword:00000002
```

.. and here's the same thing under HKCU that does:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\domains\google.com]
"https"=dword:00000002
```

I've been unable to find any updated documentation that confirms this behaviour, or provides an alternative approach to setting zone assignments at a machine level.

Plainly, I could use group policy, preference, or a login script, but I was hoping to be able to avoid these as they don't suit the scenario I'm working within.

Comment: The article you link doesn't apply to IE 11.

Comment: @Twisty Very true - but I can't find a newer one that contradicts it either.

Comment: Understood. But your question seems to suppose that document applies to IE 11. Given you really can't do that, it may be better to ask for an authoritative source explaining how it works in IE 11, citing your observation that something has changed (and the fact the only info you can find is old) as a reason for asking.

Comment: @Twisty good point.  I've modified my question.